# Is it invalid to use a single sample to estimate more than one proportion?

Tags: sampling, standard-error, inference, proportion

Lets say that I have a jar of white, black and red marbles (1000 total) but I don't know the quantity of each colour.

I now take a sample of 10 marbles from the jar which contains 3 x white, 4 x black and 3 x red marbles.

Is it fair for me to estimate the proportion of each colour and use the 'standard error of a proportion' for each colour independently?  For example, can I say that there are 30% white marbles with a margin error of $\sqrt{{p(1-p)}/{n\,}}$, and then do the same for black (40%) and red (30%)?

I am comfortable with the margin of error formula if we used 3 independent samples of 10 - with one experiment for each colour.  However, it feels like we are 'double-dipping' and losing statistical freedom in the estimates for black and red if we use a single sample, given that if we already know that 3 marbles are **not** black or red.

Apologies if I am using the wrong terminology, I am not a statistician!

Answer (score 4):

> Is it fair for me to estimate the proportion of each colour and use the 'standard error of a proportion' for each colour independently?

Yes, absolutely. It's not just fair, but also correct.

> For example, can I say that there are 30% white marbles with a margin error of $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$, and then do the same for black (40%) and red (30%)?

Think of it as binomial "red" vs "not red" say. The standard error of the proportion of red will be right.

However, if you start doing calculations that involve multiple colours, you must take their dependence into account. The counts for any two colours are negatively correlated.

It's not "double dipping" at all. You're just dealing with a multinomial, and [if you focus on just one category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Properties) vs the rest, that's binomial. All perfectly legitimate.

However, if you're talking about something akin to *marbles*, take care with the issue of sampling with replacement vs sampling without replacement.

Note that if you're not sampling with replacement your standard errors don't apply because you'd have a hypergeometric not a binomial (and the multi-colour situation is multivariate hypergeometric rather than multinomial). The variance is smaller in this case, sometimes substantially smaller.

Edit: just an additional note - the [margin of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error#Calculations_assuming_random_sampling) isn't usually taken to be one standard deviation of the sample proportion.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b, great answer. Would anything change if I didn't know what the marble colours (categories) were to begin with?

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous/confusing, sorry. It's not clear how one would talk about the proportion of 'red' if one doesn't know 'red' is a colour. Could you clarify your intent, possibly with a small illustrative example, in your question (or alternatively, in a new question)?

Comment: To clarify my follow up question: In the example above I knew that if I pull out a marble it will be either white, black or red (so I had prior knowledge of the categories and what colours I could possibly see in my sample).  Would anything be different if I didn't know what colours were in the jar before I started sampling?

Comment: I repeat my earlier comment:  "*It's not clear how one would talk about the proportion of 'red' if one doesn't know 'red' is a colour*" (that is 'a colour present in the jar'). Your standard error is a function of sample observation. Your response doesn't seem to clear this up. What, then, are you asking for, exactly? Can you, as requested before, give a small illustrative example **in your question** of the question you seek an answer to, or ask a new one? Are you asking about a SE for the proportion of reds when you draw a sample that contains 0 reds and you're not sure there are any?

Comment: I'll rephrase and post as a separate question